# Objects not shown in sculpt mode

Tags: sculpting

Blender 2.80

I have a strange effect. In my blend files I have multipe objects. All objects have been sculpted in the past.

Now all are visible as objects, can be selected, textured etc. But in sculpt workspace only one object (the last I worked on) can be shown and changed.

Searching for any reason it became worse. Now the last object is not shown in sculpt mode as well.

Comment: Try to push alt+h in Sculpt Mode.

Comment: That was one of my first ideas. (sulpt mode, edit mode, edit mode after selecting all) Sad to say it didn't work. The object seems not to be hidden.

Comment: please share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=6803" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/6803/)

sorry, took me a wile to reduce the size.

Comment: You turned on the local view. You can toggle it with the numpad/ key.

Comment: That did the trick. Using Blender for 6 month now and haven't  know about this usefull feature.

Again, something learned.
Thank you, I'd vote you up if you put your solution as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Above the 3D view port where the layout tabs are (layout shading animation... etc) just delete the sculpt tab where you have the problem and add a new sculpt tab with the + icon. Minor bug hopefully will be fixed